# Why does git phantom modification disappear after I edit .gitattributes

Tags: git, github, svg

This is really weird. I have a project, lets call it project X.

I push project X to github. 
I then check it out on a different machine. I type `git status` and I see this:

```
modified:   test/bower_components/mocha/media/logo.svg
```

What?

I diff it, and it looks *exactly* the same. One possibility is that this is a line-feed normalization issue. I know you can specify repo specific line-feed options in `.gitattributes`. So I open `.gitattributes` and see this:

```
* text=auto
```

According to [Git Doc](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html):

> This ensures that all files that git considers to be text will have
>   normalized (LF) line endings in the repository. The core.eol
>   configuration variable controls which line endings git will use for
>   normalized files in your working directory; the default is to use the
>   native line ending for your platform, or CRLF if core.autocrlf is set.

Okay, so maybe the normalization is causing git to think I changed the file or something. This is still unlikely, since both machines are running Ubuntu.

Whatever. I'll just delete it and see what happens. So I delete it, type `git status`, and see this:

```
modified:   .gitattributes
```

The `.svg` modification isn't considered to be modified anymore!

I go back and undo my change to `.gitattributes`. I then type `git status`

```
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: What does `git config core.autocrlf` returns in your repo?

Comment: that gives me false. I disabled it. The .gitattributes values overrides that setting anyway.

Comment: EXACTLY the same thing happened in our project at work and I solved it doing just like you. removing a line in .gitattributes and then reset --hard :P

Comment: @AndreasNorman yeah I still have no idea why it does that.